# Spring Boot + Kafka + Kerberos configuration

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos, spring-kafka

I am using **Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE** to connect to **Kafka 0.11** using Kerberos authentication. These are the dependencies I'm using for Kafka:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have to send messages to a Kafka server that is not under our management and I was given a Kafka username, `keytab` file and a `krb5.conf` file.

These are the properties used for testing without Kerberos:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: "10.10.20.185:9092"
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

Works fine.

How do I implement Kerberos in my app configuration? 
As I am new to Kafka and Kerberos, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the kafka documentation "Authentication using SASL/Kerberos"](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_kerberos).

> To configure SASL authentication on the clients:
>   Clients (producers, consumers, connect workers, etc) will authenticate to the cluster with their own principal (usually with the same name as the user running the client), so obtain or create these principals as needed. Then configure the JAAS configuration property for each client. Different clients within a JVM may run as different users by specifiying different principals. The property sasl.jaas.config in producer.properties or consumer.properties describes how clients like producer and consumer can connect to the Kafka Broker. The following is an example configuration for a client using a keytab (recommended for long-running processes):

```
sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
    useKeyTab=true \
    storeKey=true  \
    keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/kafka_client.keytab" \
    principal="kafka-client-1@EXAMPLE.COM";
```

> For command-line utilities like kafka-console-consumer or kafka-console-producer, kinit can be used along with "useTicketCache=true" as in:

```
sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
    useTicketCache=true;
```

> JAAS configuration for clients may alternatively be specified as a JVM parameter similar to brokers as described here. Clients use the login section named KafkaClient. This option allows only one user for all client connections from a JVM.
>
> Make sure the keytabs configured in the JAAS configuration are readable by the operating system user who is starting kafka client.
>   Optionally pass the krb5 file locations as JVM parameters to each client JVM (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html) for more details):

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/kafka/krb5.conf
```

Configure the following properties in producer.properties or consumer.properties:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT (or SASL_SSL)
sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

Comment: I've created a `jaas.conf`:
`
KafkaClient{
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=true
  keyTab="/home/tomi/user-host.keytab"
  principal="user/host@x.com";
};
`

And I start the app with `java -jar -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/tomi/jaas.conf -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/tomi/krb5.conf  kafka.jar`.
When trying to send a message I get: `sun.security.krb5.KrbException: no supported default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes`.
In my krb5.conf `default_tkt_enctypes` is defined to `aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96`.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with that information; people typically don't look for new questions in comments here - I don't have the chops to provide an answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

See this from [Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html#clients)

You need to input below in your spring boot application.yml file. Spring boot Kafka will automatically pick these config and create your consumer client with Kerberos Authentication.

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: address:port
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl:
        mechanism: GSSAPI
        kerberos:
          service:
            name: kafka
        jaas:
          config: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true storeKey=true keyTab="/path/to/keytab" principal="servicename/hostname@REALM";
```

You also need to pass `-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf` to the JVM or use static initializer in you main class to set [Kerberos configuration information](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html) (This contains details about your KDC).
Read more on [Kerberos Requirements here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html)

```java
static {
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.security.krb5.conf"));
    }
```

Make sure that your brokers also support the Security protocol provided in spring boot configs.
You can confirm these by checking the server.properties file in your Kafka brokers, i.e.

> With GSSAPI (Kerberos) enabled mechanism (Note: More than mechanism can be enabled in Kafka brokers hence supporting multiple authentication mechanisms)
>
> > sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI

> With SCRAM enabled mechanism
>
> > sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256

> With PLAIN enabled mechanism
>
> > sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN